# Bijection $F=\{ f \in\ A \to B | \forall \left(<x, y> \in\ E\right). \to \left(f\left(x\right)=f\left(y\right)\right)\} \to \left(A/E \to B\right)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let A and B be sets, and E is an equivalence relation. F is defined as follows:
$F=\{ f \in\ A \to B | \forall \left(<x, y> \in\ E\right).  \to \left(f\left(x\right)=f\left(y\right)\right)\}$

How can I find a bijection $G \in F \to \left(A/E \to B\right)$?

$A/E$ denotes the quotient set of A by E and $<x,y>$  denotes ordered pairs.

A hint or direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Every element of $A/E$ is of the form $[a]$, for some $a\in{}A$.
Define $g:F\to{}(A/E\to{}B)$ as follows:
For every $f\in{}F$, we define $g(f)$ to be a function from $A/E$ to $B$ as follows:
$$g(f)([a])=f(a)$$

Note that the domain of $g$ is indeed $F$ and that its codomain is indeed the set of functions $A/E\to{}B$

We need to prove 3 things:
(i) $g(f)$ is a well defined function for all $f\in{}F$,
(ii) $g$ is injective,
(iii) $g$ is surjective.

To prove that $g(f)$ is well defined, we need to show that if $[a]=[a']$ then $f(a)=f(a')$, that is, in a way, $g(f)([a])=g(f)([a'])$ (clearly, if this wasn't the case, then $g(f)$ wasn't a function!).
Indeed, $[a]=[a']$ implies that $f(a)=f(a')$ by definition of $F$.

To prove that $g$ is injective, let $f_1,f_2\in{}F$ and assume that $g(f_1)=g(f_2)$. then $g(f_1)([a])=g(f_2)([a])$ for all $a\in{}A$. Thus, $f_1(a)=f_2(a)$ for all $a\in{}A$. Thus, $f_1=f_2$.

I leave the proof of surjectivity to you.

Comment: Can you explain? @idok

Comment: for every $f\in{}F$, we define $g(f)$ to be the function $h=g(f):A/E\to{}B$ so that $h([a])=f(a)$.

Comment: How do you know it's a bijection? Is there an inverse function?

Comment: My answer was more of a hint. It is left to prove that $g$ is well-defined, injective and surjective. I will add the proof for well-defined and surjective to my answer, and leave injectivity for you.

Comment: Instead I decided to prove injectivity and leave surjectivity for you.

Comment: Brilliant, perfectly clear. Thank you